# Need Proof: Maximum overlap area of rectangle

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Suppose I draw multiple rectangles, each can have different length and breadth but their areas are same. Also, there is one constraint that each rectangle should follow, the center of each rectangle should be the origin in the x-y coordinate plane.

Next, I have to pick any one given rectangle out of the multiple drawn rectangles and find its overlapping area with the other rectangles. How should I prove that the overlapping area will be maximum if the picked rectangle is a square

Comment: Perhaps it will have something to do with this: some rectangles will be taller than they are wide and others wider than they are tall. Rectangles that are not squares will overlap more with one type or the other, but the square will overlap equally with both.

Comment: If your collection of "drawn" rectangles is given, then it need not be the case that any of them is a square.

Comment: @Frpzzd - yep, its intuitive that way but I'm not sure how can I prove it mathematically.

Comment: @hardmath - lets assume we can draw rectangles with equal length and breadth. :)

Comment: Even if your collection of rectangles happened to contain a square, it would not necessarily have the maximum overlap. If all rectangles (except the square) were long and thin and oriented the same way, one of those rectangles would have greater overlap than the square.

Comment: I am wondering if your collection of rectangles is not a finite collection but the set of all possible rectangles centered at the origin with some fixed area.  The Question doesn't suggest that interpretation, and indeed your drawing "multiple rectangles" suggests a finite number are in the collection.  I'm also not clear on the objective to maximize "the overlapping area".  While the overlapping area between two rectangles is unambiguous, I'd be at loss to define the area of overlap between one rectangle and many rectangles.  Finally, are rotated rectangles allowed?

Comment: @hardmath - the number of rectangles is very large but still finite. And yes, they can be aligned in any manner around the origin even rotated. The idea is to pick a rectangle which can have maximum total overlapping area with all other rectangles. I should be able to prove that the picked rectangle is a square.

Comment: This notion of "maximum total overlapping area with all other rectangles" might be more subtle than you realize.  If you cannot right down an expression for this amount, perhaps it is worth a post that reflects several possible interpretations.  In any case @Jens already described a scenario in which the collection of rectangles skews away from "square" in distribution, and thus more overlap is obtained by having one of the rectangles that agrees with the skewing of length.

Comment: As many pointed out, either I don't understand what you mean by "maximum total overlapping area", or there is no reason for that the maximizer to be a square. In the simpler case where every rectangle is axis aligned, the likely maximizer would be an "average" of the rectangles in your set, if you don't assume any sort of regularity in this set, that "average" has no reason to be close to a square, it can be any arbitrary elongated rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim is false under natural interpretations of it, hence you will not be able to prove it (at least until you clarify it).

Here is how I interpret it:

Given $n$ origin-centered rectangles $R_1, R_2, \ldots, R_n$, all of the same area, and given any index $i \leq n$, define
$$f(i) = \sum_{j \neq i}Area(R_i \cap R_j).$$

The goal is to find an $i$ which maximizes $f$. Such an $i$ clearly exists since it is the maximum of a finite set. You claim that it is maximized at an index $i$ with $R_i$ a square. This is clearly false in general.

First of all, there is nothing in the assumptions that guarantees that *any* of the rectangles will be a square. If none of the rectangles are squares then obviously it can't be maximized at a square. Furthermore, even if you add the constraint that at least one of the rectangles is a square, there is no reason to think that `f` will be maximized at such a square.

As a counter-example: if $R_1$ is the axis-aligned square of area 1, $R_2$ is the $10 \times (1/10)$ axis-aligned rectangle with long side parallel to the $x$-axis, and $R_3$ is the $20 \times (1/20)$ axis-aligned rectangle, with the long side again parallel to the $x$-axis, then it is easy to see that $f(1) = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{20} = \frac{3}{20}$, but $f(2) = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{6}{10}$. Thus $f(2) > f(1)$, so $f$ isn't maximized at the square.

Comment: +1 An even easier counterexample is a collection of several identical (or nearly identical) long thin rectangles and one square.